# Stubbing a method that returns multiple values rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Consider the following function that returns two values (let's say it's a method associated with a class `Foo`):

```
def returns_two_things()
// some logic that computes result1 and result 2
return result1, result2
end
```

I thought I could stub `returns_two_things` like this:

```
allow(@my_foo_instance).to receive(:returns_two_things) \
  .and_return("foo", "bar")
```

But only "foo" is being returned. I gather that the `and_return` method is used to tell rspec to return "foo" the first time `returns_two_things` is called and "bar" the second time. This is how I'm invoking `returns_two_things` in the code I'm trying to test

```
result1, result2 = @my_foo_instance.returns_two_things()
```

How can I get rspec to return two values from the stubbed function?

Comment: `def foo; 1, 2; end` produces `SyntaxError: unexpected ','`, so please provide a valid code sample.

Comment: `and_return(["foo", "bar"])` – you have to provide an array.

Comment: @anothermh added a return

Comment: BTW, `and_return("foo", "bar")` is used to [specify different return values for multiple calls](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls) – the first call would return `"foo"` and any further calls would return `"bar"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby does not have multivalue returns. The code example provided implicitly returns an array with 2 elements, i.e. `return "foo", "bar"` is same as `return ["foo", "bar"]`.

So the correct way to stub is:

```rb
allow(@my_foo_instance).to receive(:returns_two_things) \
  .and_return(["foo", "bar"])
```